# Javafx BorderPane.setCenter changes position of bottom region

Tags: javafx

I'm learning Javafx where in I'm trying to display an analog clock at the center and angle value of the seconds hand as a label at the left bottom the screen. If I try to increase the radius of the circle which is member of clock group that's been set to BorderPane center, it changes the position of Bottom region which displays angle value. I was expecting center region will remain within its area even if bigger dimension nodes get added(or updated) to clock group and bottom region still visible. Here is my sample code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {
    static BorderPane borderPane;
    static Group clock;
    public static Circle clockCircle;
    public static Line angHand;
    public static Text angText;
    public static Rotate angRotate;

    public static Label angLabel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        borderPane = new BorderPane();

        clock = new Group();

        clockCircle = new Circle(360, Color.RED); //increasing the radius affects other region

        angHand = new Line();
        angHand.startXProperty().bind(clockCircle.centerXProperty());
        angHand.startYProperty().bind(clockCircle.centerYProperty());
        angHand.endXProperty().bind(clockCircle.centerXProperty());
        angHand.endYProperty().bind(clockCircle.centerYProperty().subtract(clockCircle.getRadius()));

        angText = new Text();

        angRotate = new Rotate();
        angRotate.pivotXProperty().bind(clockCircle.centerXProperty());
        angRotate.pivotYProperty().bind(clockCircle.centerYProperty());

        angHand.getTransforms().addAll(angRotate);
        angText.getTransforms().addAll(angRotate);

        angLabel = new Label();
        angLabel.setText("Angle: 0");
        BorderPane.setAlignment(angLabel, Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

        clock.getChildren().addAll(clockCircle, angHand, angText);

        Button home = new Button();
        home.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(MainApp.class.getResourceAsStream("etc/home.png"))));

        borderPane.setCenter(clock);
        borderPane.setBottom(angLabel);
        borderPane.setRight(home);

        //DataReceiver objDataReceiver = new DataReceiver();
        //Thread dataRecvThread = new Thread(objDataReceiver, "DATARECVR");

        //dataRecvThread.start();

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("CLOCK");
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth(), Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. What is class `DataReceiver` ?

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/aYoUtj2) is how it looks when I run your code. I replaced "home.png" with a yellow circle, which appears in top, right corner. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Abra I've modified my code. Please go through one more time, especially the line "clockCircle = new Circle(360, Color.RED);"

Comment: No difference. And I still don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @Abra the label at the bottom left corner cannot be seen if I increase the radius of the circle. I want the bottom, right, left and top regions of the borderpane to be visible always no matter what the size/position of the node in the center region is